# jQuery .post how to add Failure

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drupal

I have the below script and it works but I want to add an alert for when something went wrong. It is part of a drupal module.

My short php:

```
ajax_function() {
    //Below is just for the failure part. I want to display the message
    drupal_json(array('status' => 'failure', 'message' => 'You cannot submit this.'));
}
```

The JS:

```
button.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var path = 'to/ajax/function';
    $.post(path, function(data) {
        //submits on success
        $('#webform').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: To clarify I want to alert message index from the JSON array from my php script not just text. How would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use: `.done` for succes, `.fail` for error and `.always` is finished

```
var yourPost = $.post(path, function(data) {
    //submits on success
    $('#webform').submit();
}) 
.done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});
```

please see: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

**UPDATE**

you can get the value of your array. like this.

```
button.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var path = 'to/ajax/function';
    $.post(path, function(data) {
        //submits on success
        if(data.status == "failure")
            //your can get "data.message" contain your message
        else
            $('#webform').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Do i need to include done and always? I only want fail and success. Also i want to include the message from the json array how would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Just use this way:

```
var path = 'to/ajax/function';
$.post(path).then(function(){

    //success code goes here

}, function(){

    //failure core goes here

});
```